# Trim() Function with Spring JPA like Query Methods

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am making a rest service that internally is using JPA to find data with a prefix (for instance: **Information** prefix).

My query method with Spring data looks like this:

```
List<Entity> findAllByFieldStartsWithIgnoreCase(String field);
```

Everything is working fine, however, there are data in the database that have the Information prefix, but also have a white space, like in the followings example:

Field:

```
Information 1
    Information 2
 Information 3
Information 4
```

Like you can see in the above examples, Information 1 does not have some white space, but Information 2 and 3 have one, or more, white spaces.

I am looking the way to ignore these spaces, I know that sql has the [**trim** function](https://estradawebgroup.com/Post/Como-eliminar-los-espacios-en-blanco-en-SQL/1036#:%7E:text=La%20funci%C3%B3n%20LTRIM%20y%20RTRIM,del%20comienzo%20de%20la%20cadena.) to make it, but in [JPA repository with Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html), with query methods, does not exist:

I would like to find a function to type the query methods like this:

```
List<Entity> findAllByField  Trim   StartsWithIgnoreCase(String field);
```

In order to execute trim function before the StartWith.

I would apprecite your help, regards.

Comment: you can use criteria query with trim function to remove leading/trailing spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a JPQL query here using the `@Query` annotation. For example, the following snippet should give you a prefix search on a trimmed column

```
@Query("select e from Entity e where trim(e.field) like concat(:field,'%')")
List<Entity> findAllByFieldStartsWithIgnoreCase(@Param("field") String field);
```

Here's a [resource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) on how to use native/JPQL queries with Hibernate